# Error outputting img html tag to php echo source

Tags: php, html

I have searched the site for an answer to my question, however the solutions have been unable to solve my problem.

My Problem is:
I have tried to add a php echo element inside of an  html tag. However it is throwing off an error as seen in the screenshot. I have tried various ways to adjust this code unsuccessfully.

I should mention that it is a simple MVC application.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rjKy0.jpg)

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: You are printing a string not an html tag ! where is the '<>' ?

Comment: so post your code and not a screenshot of it

Comment: Stack allows you to post code. perhaps you did not get the memo

Comment: remove both ' from code after "Image :"

Comment: I think you want like this

    `echo 'Image: <img src="'.$page->image .'"><br/>';  `

Comment: sorry i accidentally  re-open the question.

Answer (score 1):

You were concating wrong. Be careful with ' and ".

```
echo '<img src= " '. $page->image . ' " <br>';
```

The spaces between " are here just for readability.

And btw you can't execute PHP code inside html.

Comment: You should do the tag like this <img src="pic_mountain.jpg" alt="Mountain View" style="width:304px;height:228px;">

Comment: Ok, thank you for the explanation, I will research further on Concating. Thanks for solution as well. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

You can't separate your string like that:

```
echo 'Image' 'img src='...;
            ^
```

If you want to concatenate everything, use `.` or just put it all on the same string:

```
echo 'Image <img src="'. $yourVariable.'"/>'; ...
```

Comment: Thank you I was thinking about the concatenating using the ., appreciate the advice.

Comment: @JediMasterOrion glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

Your ' and " were in the wrong spots. Also, not that it's related to your PHP erorr but you were also missing the < /> around your image.

```
echo 'Image: <img src="' . $page->image . '" alt=""/></br>';
```